# VS 2015 does not have Windows Phone (universal) emulator for Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am trying to follow tutorials in this page:
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/

I have installed latest updates for both vs 2013 and vs 2015. When I create Windows Universal application I can see all available emulators.

Here tutorial shows there is Windows Phone (universal) emulator is installed.

[image]

For my cordova app I can run on Android emulator but I cannot find Windows Phone (universal emulator). It shows in example of the page given.

This is view of my VS:

[image]

How can I make it appear under emulators list?

Answer (score 0):

Install the the latest windows 10 mobile emulators

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/07/29/targeting-windows-10-with-your-apache-cordova-app/

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=698769